# Printing an array of pointers to strings using C leaves out the last string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stdout

I am looking to create an array of pointers to strings read from a file in C. However when I try to print out the strings copied to `stdout`, the last line of the file is always left out. 
The program also sometimes experiences a `segmentation fault` which I haven't been able to completely eliminated. It happens about 2 out of 5 times.

Here is my `input.c` code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "input.h"

#define MAXLINES 5000


void writelines(char *arr[], int l);

char *read_lines[MAXLINES];

void get_input(const char *fp) {
    FILE *contents;
    char *line;
    char *temp;
    size_t len;
    ssize_t read;
    int i;
    i = 0;
    contents = fopen(fp, "r");
    if (contents == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, contents)) != -1) {
        if ((temp = (char *) malloc(strlen(line) + 1)) == NULL) {
            printf("Could not allocate required memory.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else {
            line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
            strcpy(temp, line);
            read_lines[i++] = temp;
        }
    }
    fclose(contents);
    free(line);
    free(temp);
    writelines(read_lines, i);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void writelines(char *arr[], int l) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

My `main.c` file is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "input.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1)
        printf("Please provide a valid source code file.\n");
    else
        get_input(*(++argv));

    return 0;
}
```

I compile using `gcc main.c input.c -Wall` with no warnings or errors.

Using `gdb` I can confirm that the process runs normally.
When it experiences a segmentation fault, the back trace shows a call to `strlen` that apparently fails.

Comment: if the last line doesn't end by linefeed, your code removes the last char. You should use `strcspn` to strip the last linefeed so if it isn't here, it still works.

Comment: Why do you need `strlen` if `getline` is giving you `len`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline):

> If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program. (In this case, the value in *n is ignored.)

but in your case you're passing an *uninitialized* value to `getline` the first time, so `getline` thinks it can write to that illegal location and this is *undefined behaviour* (which explains the "It happens about 2 out of 5 times" thing)

The first fix should be to initialize `line`:

```
char *line = NULL;
```

then, why are you creating a *copy* of `line`, and you're not freeing `line` (memory leak) and you're not resetting it to `NULL`. So next time `getline` reuses the previous buffer, which may not be long enough to hold the next line.

The fix is just to store the line:

```
read_lines[i++] = line;
```

then set `line = NULL` so `getline` allocates the proper len for next line. And drop the `malloc` code, it's useless.

fixed part (you don't need to pass pointer on `len` it is ignored):

```
line = NULL;
while ((read = getline(&line, NULL, contents)) != -1) {
         read_lines[i++] = line;
         line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;  // strip off linefeed if there's one
         line = NULL;
 }
```

(linefeed strip adapted from [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input))

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Your answer mostly worked, but  the pointer `len` is needed. Otherwise no data is seemingly read.

Comment: strange as the doc states that it's not used. Well, okay, glad you made it work.